# Code actions not available in new DAX Query View

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

In the new **DAX Query View** preview feature, there is a cool workflow to Evaluate a measure, and if needed, add the measure DEFINE statement in the query through a Code Action (the light bulb in the picture below):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dax-query-view#measure-update-workflow
[image]

If I follow this workflow, the Code Action is there and works.
[image]

But if I start from a [DAX Query from the Performance Analyzer pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dax-query-view#getting-visual-dax-queries-from-performance-analyzer), there's no light bulb. If I press **Ctrl+.** to check for Code Actions, I get "No code actions available".
[image]

Is there any other way to trigger the Code Action? Any idea why this doesn't work? I'm hoping this is a bug to be fixed, because this is just too useful. I've tried editing the DAX from Performance Analyzer to simplify it, but I haven't found anything that enables the Code Action.

Comment: In the docs, under [Considerations and limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dax-query-view#considerations-and-limitations) , it has "Lightbulb quick actions for measures only displays when no DEFINE statement is in the query tab." Could that be why?

Comment: That was it. You just delete the line with DEFINE and it works. This is awesome for working with DAX!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it will not have these options if you already have a DEFINE statement in the query.

The easy workaround is to comment out or just delete the DEFINE at the top of the query
[image]

Then the Code Action is available:
[image]

And when selected will add a new DEFINE at the top:
[image]